# Fixing open bracket problem in HTML string using Python

Tags: python, string

I have the following text:

```
string = "<i>R</i> subspace  <i>{V.</i> generated by <i>{v<sub>1</sub>,...,v<sub>i</sub></i>, "
```

A careful reader might notice that there are **two brackets missing.** I was wondering, how this could be fixed using Python?

The expected output would be:

```
the <i>R</i>  subspace  <i>{V.}</i> generated by <i>{v<sub>1</sub>,...,v<sub>i</sub>}</i>,
```

One could:

1. Check: Is there a bracket after `<i>` ?
2. If yes -> Is there a bracket before `</i>` ?

How can I code this?

### Edit

I have found [this code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/180567/checking-for-balanced-brackets-in-python), that can tell you if the brackets match or not.

Comment: What goes inside the brackets? Can "</i>" appear inside brackets (i.e. does "<i>{v<i></i></i>" turn into "<i>{v<i>}</i></i>" or "<i>{v<i></i>}</i>")?

Comment: @CraigMeier Good point. The second case would be the correct one.

Comment: @CraigMeier Would you know how to already code the simpler case (first case) ?

Comment: The first case can be handled by a regex (e.g. `re.sub` with a callable `repl` param that ensures there's a final '}' for any chunk with an initial '{'). But the second case falls under https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/

Comment: @CraigMeier Thanks for your input, but I don't know how to code it with `repl`. Sorry to bother you... I see that I can do: re.sub(r'<I>, SOMETHING, string)

Comment: Another great question. However, as with your previous HTML repair question, is there any significance to the `i` in `<i>`, or should it work on arbitrary tags?

Comment: how many times this function has to be called? What generated this string? why cant you fix it manually

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks for your question: First if would be good to have it working for the `i `but of course, an extinction to arbitrary tags would be very useful for a much wider community !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following regex solution:

```
import re

string = "<i>R</i> subspace  <i>{V.</i> generated by <i>{v<sub>1</sub>,...,v<sub>i</sub></i>, "
expected = "<i>R</i> subspace  <i>{V.}</i> generated by <i>{v<sub>1</sub>,...,v<sub>i</sub>}</i>, "

fixed = re.sub(r"<(?P<tag>.*?)>({.*?)</(?P=tag)>", r"<\1>\2}</\1>", string)

print(fixed == expected) # True
```

The idea is to match a tag followed by a brace, find its closing tag, and plop the companion brace before the closing tag using the capture groups as `<\1>\2}</\1>`. Breakdown:

```
< # literal opening bracket
 (?P<tag> # open a named capture group
         .*? # lazily match any characters
            ) # end named capture group
             > # literal closing bracket
              ( # open capture group 2
               { # literal opening brace
                .*? # lazily match any characters
                   ) # end capture group 2
                    < # literal opening bracket
                     / # literal slash
                      (?P=tag) # backreference to the named group
                              > # literal closing bracket
```

If you just want `<i>`, you can use `re.sub(r"<i>({.*?)</i>", r"<i>\1}</i>", string)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this perfect answer !!